# How can I pass NA when attempt to select fails with "attempted to select less than one element"?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two data frames, a and b, both have a "state" and "year" columns (as well as others). I'm trying to transfer the value for VARX from b to a. I used this:

```
for(i in seq_along(a)) {a$VARX[[i]]<-b$VARX[[which(b$state==a$state[[i]] & b$year==a$year[[i]])]]}
```

I get this error:

> Error in `b$VARX[[which(b$state == a$state[[i]] & b$year ==`  : 
>    attempt to select less than one element

The problem seems to be that there are some rows in `a` without a corresponding row in `b`, so it can't select an element. How can I either return NA in those cases (so `a$VARX[i]=NA`), or clean a from all the cases where there's no corresponding rows in `b`?

Comment: A reproducible example will help.  Perhaps use dput() to add your data to the question.  From what I can tell, you want to overwrite values in `a$VARX` with corresponding records in `b` which are determined by matching `state` and `year` between the two data frames.  If so, using `merge()` or the `data.table` package might provide an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop is not a good choice. See this working example:

```
a=data.frame(state=c("a","b","a"),year=c("2012","2013","2014"),VARX=c(1,2,3))

###################
  state year VARX
1     a 2012    1
2     b 2013    2
3     a 2014    3
###################

b=data.frame(state=c("a","b","c"),year=c("2012","2013","2014"),VARX=c(4,5,6))

###################
  state year VARX
1     a 2012    4
2     b 2013    5
3     c 2014    6
###################

# merge a and b
c=merge(a,b,by=c("state","year"),all.x=T,sort =F,suffixes = c(".a",""))

###################
  state year VARX.a VARX
1     a 2012      1    4
2     b 2013      2    5
3     a 2014      3   NA
###################

# drop VARX in data frame a
subset(c,select=-VARX.a)

###################
  state year VARX
1     a 2012    4
2     b 2013    5
3     a 2014   NA
###################
```